# How can I change my email adress for our ServiceStack account?

Tags: servicestack

How can I change my email address for our ServiceStack account?

The currently registered email address is no longer in use.

Comment: Email [their sales email](https://servicestack.net/pricing#faq)

Comment: question is not programming-related

Answer (score 1):

Go to You  `Edit Profile & Settings`
Select `EMAIL SETTINGS` from left side then select `Edit Email Settings`